# AWS Lambda error nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, aws, lambda

Estoy intentando ejecutar la siguiente función de AWS Lambda escrita en Node.js, pero siempre obtengo errores y no sé por qué. ¿Podrías ayudarme a entender qué está mal con el siguiente código?

Código:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    try {
        const params = {
            Bucket: event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name,
            Key: event.Records[0].s3.object.key
        };
        const data = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
        
        console.log(data.Body.toString());
        
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(data.Body.toString()),
        };
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: err.message,
        };
    }
};
```

La función tiene la intención de leer un archivo desde un bucket S3 cuando se agrega un nuevo archivo, y luego imprimir su contenido en la consola. Sin embargo, siempre obtengo un error de "Access Denied" o "event.Records is not defined". ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: `AccessDenied` puede ser porque la lambda no tenga permisos para recuperar el objeto de S3. Y no soy experto en nodejs, pero los ejemplos que veo usan `event["Records"]` en vez de `event.Records`. Si aun así no funciona, prueba a sacar por el log el evento que te llega. Puede que te sirva para saber más sobre el origen del problema (quizás está mal configurado el trigger de la lambda)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta a decodificar la Key como indican un [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html):

```
const key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta el tutorial me ayudo a verificar mi problema!!